socket.io-client fails to compile (module not found) on Vercel but runs just fine on localhost
Every time I try to build the vercel app, I get this error:

Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'socket.io-client' in
'/vercel/path0/client/src/components/mainlayout/navbar' Error: Command
"npm run build" exited with 1

Ending snippet of the build logs:
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
Running "npm run build"
> client@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.
babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
  
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'socket.io-client' in '/vercel/path0/client/src/components/mainlayout/navbar'
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I've double and triple checked my package/package-lock, and I've deleted and re-installed the node_modules and package-lock.json a few times to make sure those weren't causing any issues.
package.json
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^39.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.1",
    "@iconscout/unicons": "^4.0.8",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^8.1.1",
    "@projectstorm/react-diagrams": "^7.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@tippyjs/react": "^4.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "canvasjs-react-charts": "^1.0.5",
    "docx": "^8.2.2",
    "dompurify": "^3.1.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "gsap": "^3.12.5",
    "html-docx-js": "^0.3.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^5.1.10",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "konva": "^9.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "npm": "^9.8.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-flow-renderer": "^10.3.17",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.25",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-konva": "^18.2.10",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.4",
    "react-newline-to-break": "^1.0.6",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.9",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.5",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
    "react-tag-input": "^6.8.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.10.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.7",
    "vis-network": "^9.1.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.19.4",
    "@babel/core": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/generator": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "7.19.3",
    "@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "7.19.0",
    "@babel/helper-module-transforms": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.9.0",
    "@redux-devtools/dock-monitor": "^1.4.0",
    "@redux-devtools/log-monitor": "^2.3.0",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.9.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "stackblur-canvas": "^2.7.0"
  }
}

And just to be extra thorough, here is the package.json within the socket.io-client folder in my node_modules:
{
  "name": "socket.io-client",
  "version": "4.7.5",
  "description": "Realtime application framework client",
  "keywords": [
    "realtime",
    "framework",
    "websocket",
    "tcp",
    "events",
    "client"
  ],
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "build/"
  ],
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "./build/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "./build/esm/index.js",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./dist/socket.io.js": "./dist/socket.io.js",
    "./dist/socket.io.js.map": "./dist/socket.io.js.map",
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./build/esm/index.d.ts",
        "node": "./build/esm-debug/index.js",
        "default": "./build/esm/index.js"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./build/cjs/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./build/cjs/index.js"
      }
    },
    "./debug": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./build/esm/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./build/esm-debug/index.js"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./build/cjs/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./build/cjs/index.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "types": "./build/esm/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@socket.io/component-emitter": "~3.1.0",
    "debug": "~4.3.2",
    "engine.io-client": "~6.5.2",
    "socket.io-parser": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.5",
    "@sinonjs/fake-timers": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.6",
    "@types/sinonjs__fake-timers": "^6.0.3",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^0.1.5",
    "expect.js": "0.3.1",
    "has-cors": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.58.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.0-alpha1",
    "socket.io-msgpack-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "text-blob-builder": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "tsd": "^0.17.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "rimraf ./build && tsc && tsc -p tsconfig.esm.json && ./postcompile.sh",
    "test": "npm run format:check && npm run compile && if test \"$BROWSERS\" = \"1\" ; then npm run test:browser; else npm run test:node; fi",
    "test:node": "mocha --require ts-node/register --reporter dot --require test/support/hooks.ts --timeout 5000 --exit test/index.ts",
    "test:browser": "ts-node test/browser-runner.ts",
    "test:types": "tsd",
    "build": "rollup -c support/rollup.config.umd.js && rollup -c support/rollup.config.esm.js && rollup -c support/rollup.config.umd.msgpack.js",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"*.js\" \"lib/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\" \"support/**/*.js\"",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write \"*.js\" \"lib/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\" \"support/**/*.js\"",
    "prepack": "npm run compile"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Guillermo Rauch",
      "email": "rauchg@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arnout Kazemier",
      "email": "info@3rd-eden.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vladimir Dronnikov",
      "email": "dronnikov@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Einar Otto Stangvik",
      "email": "einaros@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "tsd": {
    "directory": "test"
  },
  "browser": {
    "./test/node.ts": false
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@types/estree": "0.0.52"
  }
}

My file structure is:
.
└── client/
    └── src/
        └── components/
            └── mainlayout/
                └── navbar/
                    └── Navbar.js

And in my Navbar.js, I have the import statement:
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

Vercel's docs mentioned that sometimes there can be case-sensitivity issues, however once again I've double and triple checked the cases and there shouldn't be an issue there.
This all started when I npm installed socket.io-client. I've never had an issue installing other packages before until this one.
The fact that I have 0 issues locally, and also never had any issues installing packages prior to now has me at my wits end, so any help would be appreciated.

Have you tried adding any debug commands to run in the vercel environment? Such as ls -al node_modules/socket.io-client to verify that it's getting installed correctly?
